# Retrieving fixed point value from binary string

Tags: python, encoding, decimal

I am implementing an [Arithmetic Encoder & Decoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding). A sub-module of it deals with converting fixed point value to binary and vice verse.

The strings which are to be encoded are pretty long therefore I have to consider a lot of precision= `250`. Once I have a `Decimal` value; it is being converted to a binary string (`def decimal_to_binary_str`). The issue is to retrieve the `Decimal` value from the binary `def binary_str_to_decimal`. Can someone point the issue?

```
import decimal

def decimal_to_binary_str(f, l):
    res = ""
    var = f - int(f)
    while var != 0 and len(res) < l:
        var = var*2
        res += '{0:.250f}'.format(var)[0]
        var = var - int(var)
    return res

def binary_str_to_decimal(bit_str):
    a = decimal.Decimal(0)
    b = decimal.Decimal(1)
    res = decimal.Decimal(0.5)

    for j in bit_str:
        if j == '0':
            b -= (b-a)/2
            res = res - (b-a)/2
        elif j == '1':
            a += (b-a)/2
            res = res + (b-a)/2
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=250))
    f = decimal.Decimal('0.2157862006526829178278743649908677246339070461540076509576931506281654871337287537411826845238756634211771470806684727059082493570941004017476336218118077112203256327565095923853074403357680122784788435203804147809638828466085270584355766316314164101')
    print f
    b = decimal_to_binary_str(f, 669)
    print binary_str_to_decimal(b)


  '''
    I have marked with pipe symbol(|) the difference in what is retrieved and what was the original.
    Output: 
0.215786200652682917827874364990867724633907046154007650957693150628165487133728753741182684523875663421177147080668472705908249357094100401747633621811807711220325632756509592385307440335768012278478843|5203804147809638828466085270584355766316314164101  
0.215786200652682917827874364990867724633907046154007650957693150628165487133728753741182684523875663421177147080668472705908249357094100401747633621811807711220325632756509592385307440335768012278478843|3376547904539139004978887353289003223234434034223
    '''
```

Comment: `Decimal` is actually fixed point, not floating point.

Comment: how are you handling decimals like `decimal.Decimal('0.1')`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Doing nothing special at my end as you can see in `binary_str_to_decimal` function.

Comment: I just asked as you know the output will be pretty weird for any decimal that cannot be raised to a whole power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the **decimal_to_binary_str** function. When you stop that function after 699 bits you are truncating information. That lost of information is what you see when you convert it back to decimal. You can see this clearly if you play with different output lengths:

> ```
> f = decimal.Decimal('0.31')
> out = decimal_to_binary_str(f, 64)
> print binary_str_to_decimal(out)
> Out: 0.30999999999999999997506335003283339801782858557999134063720703125
> out = decimal_to_binary_str(f, 128)
> print binary_str_to_decimal(out)
> Out: 0.310000000000000000000000000000000000000411423022787800627789057788027785987236532944870230632528063097197446040809154510498046875
> out = decimal_to_binary_str(f, 256)
> print binary_str_to_decimal(out)
> Out: 0.3100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029362973087321111726313596333521358541794401239083356709080591798573212130752251997103125511805779970305860799416908856229783336419228618758420212841997454233933240175247192
> ```

It never really converges to the original number. The issue of finding a binary representation of a decimal number is a complex one. Look into the IEEE 754 standard and similars.